# How to use db2look to get the ddl of sequence?

Tags: db2, sequence

I was wondering how to use db2look to get the ddls of sequence.

`db2look -d my_db_name -z my_proc_schema` - I tried this but it is not showing any results.

Is there an option to directly mention the sequence name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `-e` option. That will export sequences along with a few other things. Depending on your sequences you could either use the `-z` option for schema or the `-a` option for all schemas. You may also want to use the `-o` option to output to a file.

We tend to use the following a lot where I work

```
db2look -d my_db_name -e -o my_db_name_look.sql
```

> **EDIT:** Based on the comments you have below, you can use db2look, or you could also use the system catalogs to retrieve what you need.
>
> Why not run the following:
>
> ```
> select seqschema,seqname from syscat.sequences where cycle = 'N'
> ```
>
> That will retrieve those same sequences for you, but through querying
>   and you won't have to use the db2look utility to retrieve everything
>   you want. Of course if you want the DDL, you'd still have to use
>   db2look to do that, but at least you can then use -z better to narrow
>   down you schemas or do a search to find the names that came from your
>   query.

Comment: -e exports everything from the db, isnt it ? @chris

Comment: @Nachikethas - most everything. I find it doesnt't work for federated objects unless you use the -wrapper parm (and that *before* the -e one...). But according to the documentation -e will export sequence information.

Comment: `-wrapper` - What argument is it expecting ?

Comment: I tried -e option, but it is exporting other objects like procedures which I don't wanted to get. @chris Any other thoughts ??

Comment: @Nachikethas - you don't have to worry about -wrapper unless you use federation (we do). Unfortunately there is no "just get only sequences" option. -e (everything), -u (only those objects created by a specified ID), -a (all objects including inoperative ones), or even -z (schema). No matter what way you try you will get more than your sequences. But that is ok. Just copy and paste out what you need.

Comment: Well, my task is to find out all the sequences which have `CYCLE='N'` and alter it to have CYCLE. I guess I shld do it in the hardway by using regex and extract the wanted @Chris
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nachikethas - well, if that is case.....I'll add something else to my answer.

Comment: I got the list of sequence by `CYCLE='N' ` and then did an alter. 

`db2 "ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SCHEMA.MY_SQ CACHE 20 CYCLE NO ORDER"`

thanks @chris :)

Comment: Any way to sort the output to get it more deterministic between runs? I am using it to compare different instances of the same database ...

Comment: @user35424 - I've not found a way yet. It appears to be somewhat ordered based on how things were accepted by DB2. So a full blown install of a database on one environment vs a base install and applied deltas tend to yield different orders. If I find a way to order it, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the values from:

```
db2look -d my_db_name -e | grep grep ALTER | grep SEQUENCE
```

Sure, you're still using `db2look`, but you don't have the extra baggage of yet another DDL file in your filesystem, and you cut to the detail you need.